# Annoyance in VB Script

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Struggling along trying to transfer a php script over to VB Script for a person who wants an ASP Classic program.

What the heck is going on here?

```
width = 1008
height = 1260

If width > height Then
 response.write("I am confused")
End If
```

Produces the result;

```
I am confused
```

The value for width comes out of

```
dimensions = Split(canvas_size,"x")
width = dimensions(0)
height = dimensions(1)
```

When I write them out to the screen those are the numbers that I get.

Comment: This does not produce the same results for me. Perhaps you have made a mistake somewhere else.

Comment: Why the negative vote? It's a real problem. This code really does think that 1008 is greater than 1260. Do you work for Microsoft?

Comment: I can't say why you got the negative vote. However, the code posted behaves as intended.

Comment: If I reverse it to less than then it doesn't execute the code?????

Comment: If you are splitting it from a string, you might need to convert it to a numeric value to get a proper comparison.

Comment: -1 for all the hate, vitriol, and otherwise useless and offensive commentary. **The fact that you do not know how to use a tool does not make the tool broken.** If anything, it makes *you* broken. The rage is directed in the wrong direction. Note: I do not work for Microsoft.

Comment: What is the actual contents of `canvas_size`?

Comment: It was to apply CInt and CDbl to the values as they are taken out of the strings. Thank You Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

The following code works correctly when the values are strings or numeric. There must be an additional problem.

```
width1 = "1008"
height1 = "1260"

msgbox("starting")

If width1 > height1 Then
 msgbox("bad 1")
End If

width2 = 1008
height2 = 1260

If width2 > height2 Then
 msgbox("bad 2")
End If
```

My guess is that you aren't trimming and/or converting the split values. See this example.

```
dimensions = Split("1008 x 1260","x")
width3 = dimensions(0)
height3 = dimensions(1)

' does NOT work because of the untrimmed value
If width3 > height3 Then
 msgbox("bad 3")
End If

' does work because of the conversion (which takes care of the trimming too)
If cint(width3) > cint(height3) Then
 msgbox("bad 4")
End If
```

Comment: If only he were using PHP, right? Then everything would work perfectly.

Comment: Agreed. Frustrating or not, this is still programmer error which can be resolved with a little debugging (even by someone like me who hasn't written VB in a decade).

Comment: @CodyGray I am a PHP developer, but I still disagree with you.  This is functioning as intended.  You can't blame the language when it works as intended.  +1 for your comment above.

Comment: @Nilpo: My comment here was sarcastic.

Comment: @CodyGray I see that now.  See what happens when I read threads at work? lol